# Jquery autocomplete not working in bootstrap wizard

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, jquery-autocomplete

I am using [Bootstrap Wizard](https://github.com/amoffat/bootstrap-application-wizard) in my application and I want to use autocomplete on my form fields. I followed the jquery autocomplete.

Here is the code I used straight from the website:

```
 <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script>
$(function() {
var availableTags = [
"ActionScript",
"AppleScript",
"Asp",
"BASIC",
"C",
"C++",
"Clojure",
"COBOL",
"ColdFusion",
"Erlang",
"Fortran",
"Groovy",
"Haskell",
"Java",
"JavaScript",
"Lisp",
"Perl",
"PHP",
"Python",
"Ruby",
"Scala",
"Scheme"
];
$( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
source: availableTags
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="ui-widget">
<label for="tags">Tags: </label>
<input id="tags">
</div>
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong as I am trying to integrate with the wizard, any suggestions on how to fix this would be great.

**EDIT**

here is how I wrapped the bootstrap wizard textbox I am using:

```
  <div class="wizard-input-section">
                        <p>Business Unit</p>
                        <div class="form-group">

                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <div class="ui-widget">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="tags" name="tags" placeholder="Jane Smith" data-validate="validateServerLabel">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: what does your firebug/browser console say? any error?

Comment: @lovetostrike, I am getting errors on the javascript files but it still runs fine except for the autocomplete

Comment: what errors are you seeing? I tested it on jsfiddle and it works fine. Right now, I don't see start <head> tag in your code though I don't think it's the issue.

Comment: and I also don't see the script link for the jquery-ui theme.
"Additional Notes:
    This widget requires some functional CSS, otherwise it won't work. If you build a custom theme, use the widget's specific CSS file as a starting point. "

Comment: @lovetostrike, I didn't include the css and js for the bootstrap wizard but after doing more tests its not the autocomplete code, its the integration with the wizard so I working on that now.

Comment: glad you reached the right conclusion. :) But keep in mind that you will need the jquery stylesheet too, or it would just show the text without dropdown list.

Comment: @lovetostrike, everything is included. All the correct js and css files but not sure why its not running. I think the css from the bootstrap wizard is throwing it off

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46477/discussion-between-csharpdev4evr-and-lovetostrike)

Comment: did you solve it?, if yes please post the answer